# Overriding Size of Django Admin Multi-select Widget

Tags: django, django-admin

Newbie Django question: I'd like the Django admin to display more rows of choices in the multi-select widget. I have an extremely long list to select from and the default 4 rows just isn't convenient, especially when scrolling.

Right now, that widget is rendered as **select multiple** but I'd like it to be **select multiple size="12"**. Ideally this should be for specific fields, but I can live with all fields rendering with the same size attribute.

So where would be the optimal place in Django to change that?

Answer (score 22):

I did this in the admin.py by setting a blanket size for all ManyToManyField items, for instance:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import SelectMultiple
from django.db import models
from models import *

class RiverAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = { models.ManyToManyField: {'widget': SelectMultiple(attrs={'size':'10'})}, }

admin.site.register(River, RiverAdmin)
```

Comment: Note that this will not work if `filter_horizontal` or `filter_vertical` is set for the corresponding fields in `RiverAdmin`. I've spent some time to figure this out.

Answer (score 16):

If you have a long select that will keep growing, I recommend to use an [autocomplete widget](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/auto-complete/).

Anyway, you could:

1. **[Create a ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)**, for the model in question
2. **[Override the default widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)**, for the field in question,
3. **[Set widget's size attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)** to your needs
4. **[Enable that form in ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form)**, for example

   ```
   class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = YourModel
           widgets = {
               'your_field': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 12})
           }


   class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       form = YourModelForm
   ```

Comment: In addition, you need to set either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute on the form, otherwise django (3.2) reports an error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it, is to override the formfield_for_manytomany to set the size attribute.

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        form_field = super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name in [*self.filter_horizontal]:
            form_field.widget.attrs={'size': '10'}
        return form_field
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make number of rows according to initial number of related table rows, however it does not updates dynamically (probably need to insert Javascript into admin form and query number of rows via AJAX, that would be too big to post here).

```
class ProfileAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            # Will dynamically change number of rows in select multiple, however only after server reload.
            'spec_profiles': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': SpecProfile.objects.count()})
        }

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProfileAdminForm
```