# Increase the size of multi-select box in Django admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, frontend, multi-select, django-1.8

The default multi-select box in the Django admin site is so small that it's incredibly difficult to use. How do I make the admin site's multi-select boxes vertically bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330458/overriding-size-of-django-admin-multi-select-widget) post.

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        widgets = {
            'your_field': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': 12})
        }


class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = YourModelForm
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12613779/805141 is the solution from that question I ended up using.